# environment.plist adds extra characters?

Tags: macos, terminal, plist

OSX Yosemite 10.10.3

I used environment.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>my.startup</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>sh</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>
    launchctl setenv CX_LICENSE LS
    launchctl setenv CX_LIC_SERVER 127.0.0.1
    </string>

  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

When I go to terminal and type set I get this

```
CX_LICENSE=$'LS\r'
CX_LIC_SERVER=$'127.0.0.1\r'
```

then when I try to launch a program that needs to have CX_LICENSE set up it fails.

If I in the open new terminal and run `CX_LICENSE=LS` and then start the same program from the command line using `open -n application.name` it runs correctly.

- If I do `echo -$CX_LICENSE-` in the first terminal I get `-LS`
- If I do `echo -$CX_LICENSE-` in the second terminal I get `-LS-`

I find this very strange. Could someone explain and probably suggest a fix?

Comment: Do you mean ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist If so this only worked up to Mountain Lion

Comment: You have carriage returns in your plist. More than likely the plist contains windows line endings. You need to change the line endings to newline only. You can attempt to fix the plist with `tr -d '\r' < plist > newplist` or find a text editor that uses "unix" line endings and rewrite your plist.

Comment: Do you want to create an answer from your comment? It did help. Thank you